# About if statement in Java lang

Tags: java, if-statement

i want to ask,can i insert an if statement into an if statement
i have a code like this:

```
       if(some codes && some codes || (if(some codes) && some codes))
    //then something else..
```

is it possible.i tried it but it gives an error.maybe its a syntax error maybe this is not possible if you answer i will learn :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? The second part of your example makes no sense to me. What is indended using the second if clause?

Answer (score 2):

That's a syntax error.

If you have multiple conditions that you want to test, e.g. `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, then combining them with logical operators in a single `if` statement should be enough, e.g.:

```
if (a && b || (c && d))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have different condition than your code.i have a b c but d is require an if statement.i hope i told clearly

Comment: @Caner: Please give an example of why it *needs* an `if` statement.

Comment: @Caner Oli is right.  The 'if' inside your conditional statement is unnecessary.  The inner 'if' is already assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by

> some codes
>   and
>   then something else

you might do fine with an `if... else if`

```
if(some codes && some codes )
  //  ...
else if((some codes) && some codes)
 // ...
```

If "some codes" means you're using the body of the `if` to execute statements I'd suggest refactoring to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a conditional value, you can use the `?:` notation in boolean context as follows

```
if(cond1 && cond2 || cond3 ? cond4 : cond5){...}
```

meaning if cond3==true evaluates to `if(cond1&&cond2||cond4)`, else `if(cond1&&cond2||cond5)`

example

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
int c=3;
int d=4;
if(a!=b && b!=c || a+b==c ? a+c==d : b+c==d){
    System.out.println("yup");
}else{
    System.out.println("nope");
}
```